# Firefox Webm video only plays when seeking

Tags: html, firefox, webm

An odd thing with firefox. This video will only play when it's seeked from ~6 seconds onwards

http://www.wealthplanning.tv/media/videos/introduction.webm

html link here too   http://wealthplanning.tv/media/videos/test.html

Works fine in Chrome, and even opera when inside the video tags.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was an encoding issue. Was using Miro originally, but tried it with XMedia Recode instead and that solved it.