# firefox webm not working

Tags: html, firefox, video, webm

OK, I've tried the suggestions.  I've created a web.config file on my godaddy server.  I've added the file type to both the .config and the HTML doc.  The strangest thing is that, if I load from Filezila by itself the video will run in Firefox, but if I try to run it through my website on Godaddy it won't work.  Did I mention the problem I'm having is with Firefox?

Here's my code;

```
<aside id="currentMedia">
              <video width="420" height="280" controls> 
              <source src= "video/014_0831m_101.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="images/Seq014_0831m_Precious.bmp" />
              <source src= "video/014_0831m_101.webm" type="video/webm" poster="images/Seq014_0831m_Precious.bmp" />
              
              <source src= "video/014_0831m_101.ogg" type="video/ogv" poster="images/Seq014_0831m_Precious.bmp" />
              <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5.</p>
              </video>
            </aside>
```

[live web site](http://new.firstbaptistchurchoffarrockaway.com/fbc_index.html)

It's a very simple page.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Also, my poster isn't showing up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like "video/014_0831m_101.webm" isn't there (404 result).

Comment: The index file is in the same location for all tags associated with that file.  In other word, the location of the HTML doc in relations to the video is the same as the relationshiip in comparison to the .mp4 version.  They're both in the same sub-folder.  If the index file can find the .mp4 version, then it should be able to find the .webm version.

Comment: just to add, I've converted the file using Miro Video converter as well.  Both files work on my desktop using the same program(Firefox), and I've test other doc's in the folder where the video is located on server.  Weird...

Comment: If I do a `wget http://new.firstbaptistchurchoffarrockaway.com/video/014_0831m_101.mp4` I get the file fine. However, if I change the extension to `webm` or `ogg`, wget reports 404. The webm and ogg files are not in the `video` folder (or they have a different name).

Comment: @MichaelBurr that is what has been told to me.  The only alternative that I have is to strip everything down and start over.  This web-developing stuff can be nerve racking.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Good morning Mr. Burr.  I've syncronized the folders, and now the video is present in all app's.  The only problem I have now is that I can't get the video to play when I click the play button.  I can scrub through the video and see the frames, but when I press play, it goes directly to the end of clip.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Never-mind: I found a solution.  I used one of the other clips and it worked.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634531/firefox-webm-video-only-plays-when-seeking) gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how I fixed the problem, but I think it was simple a matter of redirecting link to media.
Thanks all for your help.